# array combine of unequal length of TWo arrays

Tags: php

I need help of combination of two arrays in php.

What I have:

```
numbers = array(1, 2,3,4,5,6);
letters = array('q', 'w', 'e', 'r');
```

What I need:

```
 1 q 
 2 w
 3 e
 4 r
 5 
 6
```

Important: I will never know how many items "numbers" or "letters" array contains (only that these are never equal in length), this varies per case.

So far following has gotten me closest to goal, but this submits all the letters to each number all together :

```
   function array_combine2($arr1, $arr2) {
   return array_combine(array_intersect_key($arr1, $arr2), 
   array_intersect_key($arr2, $arr1));
   }
   foreach(array_combine2($number,$array) as $n1 => $a1)
   {
   echo $n1 . $a1."<br>";
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You get the `max` and use the classic `for` loop. Check if element `isset`, if not, use an empty string.

```
$numbers = [1, 2,3,4,5,6];
$letters = ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r'];
$result = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < max(count($numbers), count($letters)); $i++) {
    $result[] = [
        "number" => isset( $numbers[$i] ) ? $numbers[$i] : "",
        "letter" => isset( $letters[$i] ) ? $letters[$i] : "",
    ];
}

echo json_encode( $result );
```

This will result to:

```
[
    {"number": 1,"letter": "q"}, 
    {"number": 2,"letter": "w"}, 
    {"number": 3,"letter": "e"}, 
    {"number": 4,"letter": "r"}, 
    {"number": 5,"letter": ""}, 
    {"number": 6,"letter": ""}
]
```

**Update:** If you only want to `echo` the values, you can:

```
$numbers = [1, 2,3,4,5,6];
$letters = ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r'];

for ($i = 0; $i < max(count($numbers), count($letters)); $i++) {
    echo isset( $numbers[$i] ) ? $numbers[$i] : "";
    echo " ";
    echo isset( $letters[$i] ) ? $letters[$i] : "";
    echo "<br />";
}
```

This will result to:

```
1 q
2 w
3 e
4 r
5
6
```

Comment: Iwant this result pls 1 q 2 w 3 e 4 r 5 6

Answer (score 2):

```
$numbers = [1, 2,3,4,5,6];  
$letters = ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r'];
$count = 0;
$combination = array();
foreach ($numbers as $num) 
{
    $val = '';
    if (isset ($letters[$count]))
    {
        $val = $letters[$count];
    }
    $combination += array($num => $val);    
    $count ++;
}

foreach($combination as $n => $l)
{
    echo $n . $l . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: I want this result pls 1 q 2 w 3 e 4 r 5 6

Comment: @window.document as i understood, each element of `letters` should be associated anycase to the correspondant of `numbers`. So if for example the third of numbres change to `7` should remain associated to the third of `letters` (that is `e`)

Answer (score 2):

Shortest solution

```php
<?php
$numbers = array(1,2,3,4,5,6); 
$letters = array('q','w','e','r');
foreach($numbers as $key => $num) { 
    echo $num .' ';
    if (array_key_exists($key ,$letters)) // check if array element exists
    echo $letters[$key].'<br>';
    else echo "<br>";
}
```

Explainaition.

First we foreach the number array or the longer array, and we echo it's element, while doing that, we check if the index exists in the letters array, if it does then we echo that element with the number.